# How to remove `' '` in list

Tags: python, string, list

```
a=['1','2','3','4','5']
```

How to remove the ' ' in `a`

I would like to make the `a` to array
I have tried:

```
c=np.array(a)
```

and print out

```
['1' '2' '3' '4' '5']
```

But i would also want to remove the`' '`

Comment: Can you not just pass a dtype to the array constructor if you want integer values? eg: `c = np.array(a, dtype=int)`

Comment: May I understand why? There is a difference in numbers represented as strings as here and numbers as integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the 'numbers' in list `a` from strings to integers

```
list_integers = [int(num) for num in a]
list_integers = np.array(list_integers)
print(list_integers)
```

result

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

Or as mentioned in the comment

```
a = np.array(a, dtype='int')
print(a)
```

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should convert your `list` values into integer

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5']
a = [int(i) for i in a]
```